# Slow Oracle connection on Fedora virtual machine

Tags: java, oracle, database-connection, fedora

We have a Java application running on Solaris which makes a connection to Oracle and checks the database for work to perform, and it runs just fine.  We tried running the same code on a standalone Fedora system, its performance is good too.  However, when we move it to its home on a Fedora VMWare virtual machine, it can take upwards of **five minutes** for the application to make the connection to the database.  It ultimately DOES make the connection - it's just snail-slow.  We suspect it's a configuration issue somewhere but can't find it.  So far as we can tell, the two Fedora boxes have nearly identical configurations.  Has anyone run into this problem before?  If so, how did you get around it?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Mike Preston

Comment: Is the database on the same box as the Java application? If so, are you accessing `localhost` or an resolvable name/IP; and if not is something on the network causing the slowdown? Is `tns_ping` slow? Are direct connections through SQL*Plus slow too? What have you eliminated?

Comment: The database is on a separate box.  We worked with the network team to ascertain the network connections are good.  SQL*Plus is quick.  We have definitively pinpointed that the problem lies in Java making the connection from the VM.  Management is ready to pull the VM out of the equation and run the app from a baremetal box, at which point this is a moot question.  Still, I'm curious as to why the performance is different.

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is that it's opening a *lot* of connections for a pool before returning one; but either way, if the standalone box was doing the same thing it shouldn't matter (assuming that was talking to the same DB, and was on the same network as the VM one). Presumably you've been able to narrow it down to a small section of Java code, if not a single statement?

Comment: It appears the solution provided for in the answer I posted does not completely solve the problem.  While it solves the five-minute connection problem, we are still having intermittent connection problems where, sometimes the connection is quick and responsive and sometimes the connection takes nearly two minutes to perform.  This is unacceptable.  Any idea why this would take two minutes to connect?  Oh, we also took the app off the VM and put it on a baremetal box and are still having problems.

Comment: Afraid not really, but I'd be looking at whether there's a driver issue, particularly if you're mixing 32- and 64-bit; i.e check you're using the 32-bit driver (and the right version) with the 32-bit JVM, even if it's a 64-bit DB. And also if you're using connection pooling, the pool size and configuration for opening/testing new connections. Not sure this can be diagnosed remotely though, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  We updated the driver to the current ojdbc6.jar but that doesn't seem to matter.  Good idea just the same.  We are noting one peculiarity - when I make changes to the app - add debug code, etc., and run the app, the first run is nice and quick.  Subsequent runs are slow.  I verified we are closing the connection before the app exits, so it's not like it's trying to open an already-opened connection.  Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.usn-it.de/index.php/2009/02/20/oracle-11g-jdbc-driver-hangs-blocked-by-devrandom-entropy-pool-empty/) is the solution which settled the issue...our headless development server was only occasionally getting any keyboard activity to fill the entropy pool (please read the article - I won't try to explain it here) and I assume it was blocking until there was enough "noise" to generate the requisite random numbers.Since there is only one other developer working on the system, it might take a couple of minutes to fill the buffer.  Once the buffer was full it went ahead and executed the connection as expected.  That also explains why we sometimes would see crisp performance followed by slow.  In a nutshell, we added the string "-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom" to the Korn shell script between the call to java and the jar file name and now it works like a champ.  Here's the full command string:

/usr/bin/java -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -jar $1 $2 $PID

If you DO read the article, be sure to read the comments below.  One of them is really funny!

Answer (score 1):

Found it!  When we are running under Solaris, we are running a 32-bit JVM with 32-bit extensions.  We are executing through a Korn shell script and had an added -d64 flag to coerce 64-bit processing.  On the Linux boxes we removed the -d64 flag from the shell script and everybody's happy.  Thanks Alex for your thoughts and assistance.